# PKCS#7 certificate with Httpclient in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, pkcs#7

I'm trying to read a PKCS#7 certificate with Httpclient. But getting error.

```
var certPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Certificates/", certName);
var certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certCollection.Import(certPath);
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certCollection);
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = await client.SendAsync(url, requestMessage);
```

Error:
WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS Secure channel.

Comment: Where does the error occur? Is there an inner exception with some more information? Can you check the fingerprint of the certificate to verify that it is the right one? Is the TLS version correct?

Comment: HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. If I try to install that certificate in my local it works fine.

Comment: A cert from a PKCS#7 file won’t have a private key. That’s probably what’s going wrong.